# Class member pointer's property returns a random value

Tags: c++, oop

I am implementing a LinkedList in C++. After initializing the LinkedList, the value of the head is returned correctly (0). However, after calling another function from the LinkedList, the value of the head suddenly changes (825533248 is outputted). This seems strange, considering that I did not make any modifications to the head between initializing the LinkedList and calling the function.

Below is my class declaration (declaration.hpp):'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class LinkedList
{
private:
   Node *head;

public:
   LinkedList(int v);
   void insert(int v);

   static void solution();
};

typedef struct Node
{
   int val;
   bool flag;
   Node *next;
} Node;
```

And below is the implementation of my class:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

#include "datastructure.hpp"

using namespace std;

void LinkedList::insert(int v)
{
    cout << head->val << endl; // OUTPUTS 825533248
}

LinkedList::LinkedList(int v)
{
    Node headNodeObject = {v, true, NULL};
    head = &headNodeObject; // Convert head from object to pointer
}

void LinkedList::solution()
{
    LinkedList linkedList = LinkedList(0);

    // Test insertion
    linkedList.insert(1);
}
```

Below is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <datastructure.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    LinkedList::solution();
}
```

Comment: You can't store a pointer to a local object then dereference it later, the object no longer exists

Comment: @AlanBirtles What would a possible solution be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node headNodeObject = {v, true, NULL};
```

This object is stack-allocated, which means it's destroyed at the end of its scope: your constructor. Keeping a pointer on it and dereferencing that pointer after it's destroyed is Undefined Behavior (might display junk, might crash, ...). Make an heap-allocated object instead:

```
head = new Node {v, true, NULL};
```

BUT it means you'll need to `delete` it in your destructor (and properly freeing a linked list in the right order is a non-trivial operation), otherwise you'll get a memory leak.

My advice: use `std::unique_ptr<Node>` instead of `Node*`.